# excel search the first ocurrence of 2 alternatives

Tags: excel

I have the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-";A1)+1)
```

what I need

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-" OR "+";A1)+1)
```

So I need the search formula to find the "-" or the "+" .

Data example

LA ARTLENS 1.56 70MM **-200-025/-225+025**

LA ARTLENS 1.56 65MM **+075-050/+025+050**

Appreciate any help

Comment: Does the first one work? if it does not, what is wrong? And the second?

Comment: yes the first one work, but I need that when it find one or the other

Comment: Show a clear example of the contents of cell A1 and what you want the result to be.

Comment: Yes, a good [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would do wonders to help us help you

Comment: I updated with a data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the `MIN` value for either and use that:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH("-",A1),SEARCH("+",A1))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so could I cheat and find the "MM"?

As in:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-SEARCH("MM";A1)-3)
```

This will only work if the MM is always there...

Edit it's -3 not +3... if you need the sign before the number it is -2